# String literal not interpreted as type String

Tags: string, scala

I'm trying to implement a simple subclass of `Iterable[String]`, and I'm encountering something that seems a bit strange to me.  My code is as follows:

```
class ItString[String] extends Iterable[String]{
    override def iterator: Iterator[String] = new Iterator[String] {
        def hasNext = true
        def next = "/"
    }
}
```

My IDE complains that it's expecting a `String` but it's actually of type `String`, and when trying to compile, it further reveals that the problem is that it requires `String` but that the literal is actually of type `java.lang.String`.  Now, I can fix this by changing it to `"/".asInstanceOf[String]`, but I'd like to know why Scala isn't recognising the type correctly.

Comment: Not sure what is your problem. I can get the following to compile (please insert newlines as requires, since SO comments don't allow multiline code blocks):

`class ItString extends Iterable[String] {
  override def iterator: Iterator[String] = new Iterator[String] {
    def hasNext = true
    def next = "/"
  }
}`

Comment: Well, your comment helped me find the problem - I wrote `class ItString[String] extends...` instead of `class ItString extends...` @HugoSFerreira if you want to write up an answer explaining why that was wrong, you deserve the credit for helping me find it.

Comment: Sure, glad to have helped :)

Comment: Java and Scala don't have different `String`s. The other `String` it's talking about is the one that you declared as a generic type.

Comment: @ChrisMartin yeah, I realize that now...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since I can get the following to compile:

```
class ItString extends Iterable[String] {
  override def iterator: Iterator[String] = new Iterator[String] {
    def hasNext = true
    def next = "/"
  }
}
```

I can deduce that your problem is with writing:

```
class ItString[String] extends ...
```

What's going on is that this occurrence of `String` doesn't refer to the type `java.lang.String`, but it is instead an unknown parameterised type (like `T` or `A`).  So, when you write `[String]`, this means *some unknown type that will be determined by the implementing class* rather than *the `String` type that you intended*.